# AngularJS Component: How to avoid watchers for unused bindings

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I have a component repeating quite a few times and would like to avoid excessive watching.

```
  angular
    .module('myModule')
    .component('component', {
      template: '',
      bindings: {
        code: '@',
        problemBinding: '<',
      },
      controller: componentController,
    });
```

Each `<` binding seems to create a watcher despite the fact that most of the components are not using `problem-binding` argument in the html. This is demonstrated in [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LYKAxNWGlGBQlh2mnsSw) where each new `<` binding creates as many watchers as the component is being repeated.

Is there a way to use `problemBinding` so that it creates a watcher for the component if and only if the argument is being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  angular
    .module('myModule')
    .component('component', {
      template: '',
      bindings: {
        code: '@',
        problemBinding: '<?',
      },
      controller: componentController,
    });
```

All 4 kinds of bindings (`@`, `=`, `<`, and `&`) can be made optional by adding `?` to the expression. The marker must come after the mode and before the attribute name.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)

Comment: Perfect! Didn't come to think of that. Thanks for the code example!

Answer (score 1):

If your most of the components are not using 'problemBinding', make it optional otherwise it will create watch for that binding in spite of being used. Can refer angular docs.

Comment: That did it. Thanks for your help!